# Streamlining image creation in Winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

From my understanding, an image in Winapi requires:

- One HDC
- One HBITMAP where the file is loaded
- One "old" HBITMAP

Keeping track of these variables would be quite a chore, meaning this is a good situation for making a class out of it. Thus, everything from draw calls to animating could be done so much smoother.

Here's what I got so far:

```
class vec2i {    //Generic class expressing two integers
public:
    vec2i() {};
    vec2i(int i, int j) : x(i), y(j) {};
    bool operator==(vec2i & ptr) { return x == ptr.x && y == ptr.y; };
    bool operator!=(vec2i & ptr) { return x != ptr.x && y != ptr.y; };
    int x = 0, y = 0;
};

class sprite {    //Sprite class
public:
    sprite() {};

    sprite(HDC hdc, const std::string str, const vec2i d) : dim(d) {    //Full constructor
        handle = hdc;
        bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, str.c_str(), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(handle, bmp);
    };

    ~sprite() {
        SelectObject(handle, old);
        DeleteObject(bmp);
        DeleteDC(handle);
   };

    void draw(HDC & param) {    //Simplified draw call
        TransparentBlt(param, pos.x, pos.y, dim.x, dim.y, handle, 0, 0, dim.x, dim.y, COLORREF(RGB(255, 0, 255)));
    };

private:
    vec2i       pos, dim;
    HDC         handle;
    HBITMAP     bmp, old;
};
```

Main file:

```
bool    running = true;
HDC     hDC;
sprite sprites;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void    init(HWND);
void    cleanUp(HWND);
void    render();
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR 
lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)"Application could not be initialised", (LPCSTR)"ERROR", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    MSG Msg;
    while (running == true) {
        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
        render(); 
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void render()
{
    Rectangle(hDC, 0, 0, 800, 600);
    sprites.draw(hDC);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void init(HWND hWnd) {
    hDC     = GetDC(hWnd);
    sprites = sprite(CreateCompatibleDC(hDC), "landscape.bmp", vec2i(224, 150));
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void cleanUp(HWND hWnd) {
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
    running = false;
    PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        init(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        cleanUp(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Main file got a bit lengthy, but I've tried to strip away all irrelevant content.

However, this class does not seem to draw. The images are loaded, as the HBITMAP variables contain some sort of data, but the TransparentBlt function returns false. Writing everything in the same cpp seems to work, so I don't see what the problem is.

EDIT: Everything worked when I removed the destructor. Putting the destructor as a separate function and calling it before the program exits solved my problem.

Comment: Please show how you are initialising and using this class (i.e. provide a [MCVE]).

Comment: @JonathanPotter Is this sufficient?

Comment: Seriously?  Windows defines a POINT struct and a SIZE struct.  You are going to define your own vec2i class?  Not a good idea.  Windows already has APIs compatible to those two structs, and your structs are not going to be compatible.If you wanted to make something useful, you would derive classes from those structs like MFC does with CPoint and CSize. Also, you are calling DeleteObject(old). VERY, VERY, VERY bad idea.  All your sprite class has that is useful is one method doing the TransparentBlt.  You'd be better off putting it in a function and forgetting the class.

Comment: Also, I don't think your code will work for images that are defined to have an ID and not a string identifier.  I think you'll have problems when you call  MAKEINTRESOURCE() with some ID and try to pass it to the constructor.  Pretty sure very bad things will happen inside the std::string constructor. MAKEINTRESOURCE() turns an ID into a string pointer, but it is not really addressable or copyable.  The WIN32 APIs recognize the special format of the string and don't blow up.  Pass it to the std:string constructor and it will probably blow up.  If it doesn't, it will not construct a usable str.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson I am entering the Winapi world from the SFML perspective, where the vec2i class is commonly used. I did not know there already existed a win32 equivalent. I will re-write the class using one of the already existing structs. Do you mind elaborating on why calling DeleteObject is a bad idea? My class is very bare bones right now because I stripped functions from it so that you wouldn't have to read through unnecessary information. Besides that, I aspire to add functionality as is needed during the development of the class. First step is to make it work.

Comment: It's not the call to `DeleteObject` that's bad. It's the call that passes `old` as the argument. That `HBITMAP` is owned by the DC, not your class. It's the responsibility of the DC to clean that up. If that doesn't make sense you can remember a simpler rule: Do not delete any resources that are still selected into a DC.

Comment: Why isn't the CreateCompatibleDC() inside of the class?  You don't seem to be calling ReleaseDC() for the GetDC(). You have non descriptive names for variables. You know you should do better. There should be some sensible naming convention.  For Windows, consider Hungarian notation for C++ or some other naming convention. "param" for an HDC? Why not hdc? Or, hdcIn? You don't need to pass the HDC as a reference.  It is a value type.  You would only need to pass by reference if you were going to change the value that goes back to the caller...and I shudder to think of that happening with an HDC.